# How to get Viewcontroller Reference in Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have one Application where my application structure is below.

- **Application**

  - FirstViewController
  - SecondViewController
- **ABCFramework**

  - ABCViewController

In My **ABCFramework**, I need FirstViewController object but I am not able to import or find FirstViewController inside the framework.

Answer (score 0):

The framework should work independently without being bound to your current application.

The best way to achieve this would be to use the delegate pattern for your application to respond to events triggered from the framework. An example below for a user logging into the application

So you could do something like this:

```
protocol ABCFrameworkProfileDelegate: AnyObject {
    func userDidLogin()
    func authenticationFailed(withError: Error)
}
```

Then in your application:

```
import ABCFramework

// maybe on button tap?
let authService = ABCAuthService()
authService.login(username: "user", password: "pwd")

// once the login request completes either this or the failed method should be called.
func userDidLogin() {
    let vc = FirstViewController() 
    push(vc, animated: true)
}
```

This way your application can manage which views to show based on what events occur.

Comment: i did same but object of vc returning nil

Comment: that is not what i suggested you do, that is the other answer. your framework should not need to know about types used in the application

Comment: what i need to do to get access of FirstViewController in ABCFramework

Comment: You are not reading what i am putting, or not understanding... **do not do that**. the framework should never have to know about a view controller that isn't part of the framework